# Implicit Conversion Error

Tags: c#

Please suggest me the change too..
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> eventIDs = new List<int>() { 53,90,344,2223,2225,4497,5512};
            MatchNumbers(eventIDs,2200,2300);

        }
        public static void MatchNumbers(IEnumerable<uint> eventsSet, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
        {
            if (upperBound < lowerBound)
                throw new Exception("Lower bound cant be bigger");
            List<int> itemSet = (List<int>)eventsSet;
            for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
            {
                int result = itemSet.BinarySearch(i);
                if (result >= 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Found{0}", i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler has already found the error for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Please suggest me the change too..

Do either one of these:

- Make your method accept an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `IEnumerable<uint>`.
- Use `List<uint>` instead of `List<int>`.

`int` represents a signed range of 32-bit integers while `uint` represents an unsigned range of 32-bit integers. Due to the difference in range of values, you can't interchange classes of both generic types `int` and `uint`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't cast `uint` into `int`.

Comment: This is completely wrong; you **can** cast `uint` to `int`. Only in the cases of overflow, unchecked casts result in nothing more than an overflow while checked casts throw an exception.

Comment: Ok, I should have said they are different types - they can be cast into each other but List<int> and List<uint> are not the same.

Comment: thank u everybody..im a complete newbie & thanks for being patient with me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<uint> itemSet = eventsSet.toList();
```